# Can I pass a facebook id + token to a Rails Devise service to authenticate a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I have a Rails web service running with Devise + OmniAuth. I have users authenticating against Facebook Connect on a mobile device. I then want the mobile device to establish a session with our web services. What do I need to pass to device from the mobile client to establish this session? Is there a code sample on the Rails side of things of how to handle this id+token that is passed from facebook -> mobile -> web service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not found a good way of doing this. I am not using `:omniauthable` either, I'm using OmniAuth and Devise separately as seen in the Railscast episode where there are two tables `users` and `authentications`. It's kinda hacky and only works for Facebook.

Basically, send your access_token from the iPhone to the server over SSL, or something similar. You have to check with OmniAuth first and if you are granted access, then you can manually create a session with OmniAuth by going something like:

I did get something to work by doing this though:

```
FB = OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook.new("nothing") 

client = ::OAuth2::Client.new("nothing", "nothing", FB.client_options) 

cached_token = "app_id_part|session_id_part|token_part" # or maybe you sent it from the iPhone
access_token = ::OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client, cached_token)  

FB.instance_variable_set("@access_token", access_token) 

FB.auth_hash 
# You will either get a hash or get this error:
# OAuth2::AccessDenied: Received HTTP 401 during request.
```

After that you lookup the user info you need to find the user via your Authentications table:

```
@user = Authentication.where(:uid => FB.auth_hash["uid"], :provider => "facebook").first.user
```

Now we create a session:

```
sign_in_and_redirect(:user, @user)

# or, perhaps

sign_in(@user, :bypass => true)
```

Comment: Hey Dex, what omniauth-facebook gem are you using? I cannot get this to work using https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

Comment: I used just plain ole Omniauth. It looks like Omniauth was recently overhauled, so this probably only works with version 0.3.2 and below.

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time with this, so I will post my answer here for anyone else. This is inspired by Dex's answer above.

```
FB = OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook.new("APP_ID", "APP_SECRET") 
client = OAuth2::Client.new("APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", FB.options.client_options) 
token = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(client,'ACCESS_TOKEN', FB.options.access_token_options)
FB.access_token = token
FB.auth_hash
```

Any suggestions for improving this would be appreciated.

The snippet above allows me to get a auth_hash by querying facebook with the an access_token

I am using this gem: github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook

Comment: You don't really need the APP_ID and APP_SECRET, the whole point is to get the access token. The question is assuming you already got this from the mobile device.